# How to add a shared resource in a multi project solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2013 that hosts different projects of different types (three `Windows WPFs`, one `WebAPI` and a `Windows Service`)
something like this:

[image: view of solution in VS 2013]

I want to add shared resources like `string tables` (`global messages`, `common errors`, etc) in the `resource.resx` file that is accessible to all. Ideally this file is placed in the "Common" folder and this common folder has been placed in the root of *solution folder*.

How can i do this?

I've tried with below steps:

1. Adding a "New Solution Folder" to the solution and "Add"->"New Item..." but there is no new "Resource File".
2. Create a new "Common" folder in windows explorer, drag and drop it from windows explorer to solution explorer. but by this method i was just able to add it to projects not folders(and even in projects, VS "copies" that folder to project folder and changing files in that project only affects copied folder and not the common one)

Comment: post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all your resources in a shared project.

1. Create a new project, call it, for example `ParkingResources`.
2. For any project that requires these resources, add a reference to the new project.
3. In your consumer projects, you should now be able to access the shared resources.

Comment: I've seen varying implementations of this from using a .resx file that's linked in the project's properties to designating individual assets as embedded resources with a Custom Tool Namespace declared. Do you have a recommendation one way or another for WPF type applications as apparently .resx is frowned upon.